# Can anyone identify this Lego piece? Clear red Bionicle head with clip?

Tags: part-identification, bionicle

I got this in a big box of LEGO from my cousin and this was in there. When I asked him he said he didn't know anything about it. I also couldn't find anything on the Internet about it. It has no identification number or any other marking except Lego 2003. I was wondering if this was a prototype. If anyone can identify it I will be very happy.

[image: It appears to be a Bionicle head but I can't find the set it comes in.]

Comment: Is there a number anywhere on it, maybe next to the Lego brand?

Comment: Looks like it's got a "(c) LEGO 2005" (or maybe 2003) on it.

Comment: IDK what it is, but it looks similar to [a BIONICLE Toa Mata head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32553). What does the back look like? Is there something inside it?

Comment: Whatever this is, it's not one of a kind. [This eBay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Lego-Bionicle-Replacement-Part-Head-U-/401500327709), however, contains no information on it other than the possibility of it being a replacement part. No part number.

Comment: Can we get more pictures from other angles?

Comment: Maybe put something known in the pictures, so we get an idea of scale.

Answer (score 16):

It's from a [tooth brush](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=45589#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). It is the thing that covers the brush itself. [Here](https://www.ebay.com/p/Colgate-Lego-Bionicle-Tahu-Nuva-Battery-Operated-Toothbrush/1500026562) is a better picture of the green one.

[image]

Another picture :

[image]